# Explain why you could have have predicted the result... By inspection: $\int^2_0 \int^{4-x^2}_0 x^3 dydx = \frac{16}{3} units^3 $

Tags: calculus

Hey i was asked to evaluate the integrand $\int_d x^3 dxdy$ Where D is the region above the x-axis and below the parabola $x^2+y=4$. I found this to be $\frac{16}{3} units^3 $.

$$ \int^2_0 \int^{4-x^2}_0 x^3 dydx   $$
$$ \int^2_0 4x^3-x^5 = \frac{16}{3} units^3  $$

But now i'm being asked

> "Explain why you could have have predicted the result... By inspection"

Comment: IS  D  the region above the x-axis and under the parabola and  just for  $x\geq 0$ ? (according to your integration  it is !)

Comment: Yes It is above x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Nizar points out in his comment, in your iterated integral you've only considered the right half of the region $R$. When you consider the full region of integration given in the problem the iterated integral should be $$\int_{-2}^2\int_0^{4-x^2}x^3dydx$$ which you can compute to be $0$. So the question now is how could we have seen this would be $0$ without actually evaluating the integral. The answer is to exploit the facts that (a) the integrand $x^3$ is an *odd* function of $x$, and (b) that the region of integration is symmetric across the $y$-axis. Essentially, when you're integrating over the right half of $D$, where $x > 0$, the integrand $x^3$ is positive; however all of this positive contribution to the integral from the right half is canceled out by the matching (now negative) contribution of $x^3$ when integrating over the left half, when $x<0$.

As a one variable analogue, you know that $\int_{-C}^C x^3dx = 0$ without going through the integral computation, because $x^3$ is in odd function of $x$ and the interval of integration $[-C,C]$ is symmetric across the origin.

Comment: Thanks  a lot froggie. I got confused because isn't  that half below x and hence not above it?

Comment: Hey isn't $\int^0_{-2}$ below zero?

Comment: @kingportable Have you been taught green's theorem to understand what I have said

Comment: I have not satish just double integrals

Answer (score 1):

You can use Green's theorem and find the line integral with the curve parametrized by $x = t$ $y = 4-t^2 $ and thus $r = t\hat i + (4-t^2)\hat j$ and

$F = 0\hat i + x^3\hat j = t^3\hat j$ $\rightarrow $ $\int_C F.r$ with$ R = \text{{x,y| 0<x<2, 0<y<4-x^2}} $ 
$$\int_C F.r = \int_{0}^{2}(t^3)(4-t^2)dt =\frac{16}{3}$$